# Is this proof about the Lie brackets and flows correct as given?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347657/lie-bracket-and-flows-on-manifold), Fredrik Meyer gives a [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1348067/185631) to the following formula(Please see the conditions and the meaning of notations in the link):

> $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \alpha(t) = [X,Y](p)$, where
>   $\alpha(t):= \phi_{-\sqrt{t}}^Y \circ \phi_{-\sqrt{t}}^X \circ \phi_{\sqrt{t}}^Y \circ \phi_{\sqrt {t}}^X$.

I think Fredrik's proof is nice everywhere except for here(the last formula)

> Now we use that $(\phi_h^X)^{-1}=\phi_{-h}^X$ to get from
>   $
> \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {1}{h^2}\left[ f \circ \phi_h^Y \circ \phi_h^X(p) - f \circ \phi_h^X \circ \phi_h^Y(p) \right] 
> $
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {1}{h^2}\left[ f- f \circ \phi_h^X \circ \phi_h^Y \circ \phi_{-h}^X \circ \phi_{-h}^Y(p) \right]  \tag{1}
> \end{equation}

I wonder why this is correct as given. I think by using that $(\phi_h^X)^{-1}=\phi_{-h}^X$ we can get

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {1}{h^2}\left[ f\circ \phi_h^Y \circ \phi_h^X(p)- f \circ \phi_h^X \circ \phi_h^Y \circ \phi_{-h}^X \circ \phi_{-h}^Y \circ \phi_h^Y \circ \phi_h^X(p) \right] \tag{2}$$

But it is hard to see why (2) actually implies (1). So I even suspect that his proof is not correct.Can anybody explain it to me or show me how to correct it?

Intuitively $\phi_h^Y \circ \phi_h^X(p)$ somehow "converges" to $p$. But in the formal proof, I am afraid we can't take the limit of this part first.

Ps: I haven't read through [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673521/flows-and-lie-brackets-beta-not-a-priori-smooth-at-t-0?rq=1) given by Owen Barrett, but I feel like the proof using Taylor expansion is too long and prefer a direct proof.